# Typescript compiler doesn't recognize that an object entry might not exist

Tags: typescript

Is there an option available to force the Typescript compiler to recognize that requesting a property value from a generic object might be `undefined` if the object doesn't contain that property.

I want that the following code snippet fails to compile:

```
const keyValueMap: {[key: string]: string} = {};
keyValueMap["foo"]="bar";

//I want the next line to cause a compile error
//because the type should be string | undefined
const valueOrUndefined: string = keyValueMap["someKey"];
```

because the type of `valueOrUndefined` should be `string | undefined` and not `string`.

The compiler correctly detects this problem when the key is a type:

```
type CustomType = "Option1" | "Option2";
const keyFromTypeValueMap: {[P in CustomType]?: string} = {}

//The compiler correctly complains about the next line
const secondValueOrUndefined: string = keyFromTypeValueMap["Option1"];
```

The problem is that I have some of these objects where I don't know all the possible keys up front, so switching to a type is not a viable workaround.

[Link to the Typescript Playground with this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4DUCGAbArggsmgBwC4YBvAbUSROgCcBLMAcwF0aoHmBfGAXjK4BuAFBV02PIXIAiAGYgQ0lr2kAjNLWkjhoSLABumHAHlaAVTAATBLMYJL7Tkz7xk4nPgIyIIALYIAaWQlbSgkAgQYAGEsaD8AFXDI-mljAih6cABGaRgAHxhU9MywACYtHXBoVyQAMVoEpPdJYjJyAAUYRmjYqEaIlgB%20R0YmHn5SLkq9GAgEXUtm0wtrWzB7EeYXKnr%20hGbPGTSM7JDhIA)

Comment: `{[key: string]: string}` says for _any_ string key, there'll be a string value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In practice it doesn't, otherwise indexed types would not be useful - it's just that the language designers made a conscious choice to prefer convenience over soundness (in this case and in several other cases).

Comment: @kaya3 no it doesn't (can't, really!) in practice, but that's what the type tells the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you want is that of the [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess), which you can enable on the command-line or in your `tsconfig.json` file.

The reason the compiler gives you `string | undefined` in the second example is because your type uses the `?` syntax for an optional property; you can do the same like `{[key in string]?: string}`, if you want a workaround that doesn't involve changing the project configuration. Note that this is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), not an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

Comment: I thought about using `{[key: string]?: string}` [but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4DUCGAbArggsmgBwC4YBvAbUSROgCcBLMAcwF0B+GqB5gXxgF4yPANxA), so I thought that was not possible

Comment: @Robin Strange, I thought this was allowed; I've edited.